# Row_Number() OVER PARTITION BY based on a value in column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

[image]

Table Name: L

I'm currently working with a dataset that aims to offer insights on customer support cases. In the example above, you can see the progression of case 123376 from reopened to answered.

When I use the partition function `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY L.CaseNumber, L.[Status], L.NextDate ORDER BY L.[Date] ASC)` then I get the `Row_Number` as above. However, once the case status is answered and the next date is `NULL`, then I want to delete the rows for that case that come after, meaning I only want to keep the first row for Next Date `NULL` (in a single case number) and delete the others. Is there a way to have row numbers over partition so that the result looks like this or any other approach? [image]

Comment: Take `Status` out of your `PARTITION BY` clause.

Comment: And please don't post pictures of data or code. Plain text can be copied and pasted so that other users can provide you with better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am wondering if the following expression might do what you want - at least, I think that it should work for your sample data:

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER (
    PARTITION BY L.CaseNumber, L.[Status], L.NextDate 
    ORDER BY COALESCE(l.NexDate, L.[Date])
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The issue is that this also ranks the first 3 rows with Status 'Reopened' as 1, 2, 3 as well and I need to keep those rows in the table. So, I need an idea to apply the rank or row number to the case rows that have next date as NULL

Comment: @SalmanTahir: I understand. I edited my answer a little, is is better now?

Comment: Interesting solution! Works perfectly. Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to consider the case where [Next Date] can vary?
The below is a window query that helps to remove all consecutive nulls from [Next Date], and never get affected by the pattern of [Next Date].

```sql
with more as (
    select 
        L.*,
        case when
        LAG(L.[Next Date])
        over (
            partition by L.[CaseNumber]
            order by L.[Date], L.[Next Date]
        )
        is null then 1 end as [Last Is Null]
    from L
)
select * from more where more.[Next Date] is null and more.[Last Is Null] = 1
```

NOTE: just turn the last `select *` into `delete` to perform a deletion.

Comment: I tweaked it a bit as: (CASE 
WHEN LAG(M.[NextDate]) OVER (PARTITION BY M.[CaseNumber] ORDER BY M.[CalendarDate], M.[NextDate])
IS NULL AND M.NextDate IS NULL AND M.[Status Change]='Answered' 
THEN 1 END) AS [Last Is Null]                   This makes sure that the focus is only on the Status = Answered. We can also get the first row of Answered and delete the others. Also, good idea to bring M.[Next Date] IS NULL into the CASE WHEN function. This way the first row of the LAG on each case number is not marked as NULL be default.  Thanks again!